How to use upi_india dependency (v3.0.1) in Flutter project after JCenter deprecation?
"I'm developing a Flutter application that requires UPI (Unified Payments Interface) integration for seamless transactions. I'm currently using the upi_india dependency (version 3.0.1) to achieve this functionality.
However, I'm encountering errors during the build process due to the recent deprecation of JCenter, a repository that previously hosted the upi_india library. These errors prevent me from successfully integrating UPI transactions into my application.
Here's a relevant snippet from my pubspec.yaml file :
dependencies:
  upi_india: ^3.0.1

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists:

Updated the Gradle version to a more recent version.
Cleared the Flutter project cache using flutter clean and flutter pub get."

